# Can I use angular diameter to determine the apparent size of an object at a given distance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I believe this question uses Angular Diameter to determine the answer but I'm not sure how to use it.

**Question:** If a widget is 10 meters wide and it is positioned 1,000 meters from the observer how wide will it appear?  How wide will it appear at 2,000 meters?  Is Angular Diameter used for this?

Using [this online calculator](https://www.easycalculation.com/algebra/angular-diameter-calculator.php) I inputted 10 meters for Linear Size and 1000 meters for Distance to Object.  It returned an Angular Diameter of 0.572953020554149.  But how does this help me determine the apparent size of an object at a given distance?  Or alternately am I using the wrong formula?

**Backstory:**
I can find many references to Angular Diameter on both [Google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=YRBxWpWxFs6KjwP4oLGABA&q=angular%20diameter&oq=angular%20diameter&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i71k1l4.0.0.0.1218243.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.DleaB_AlTnE) and [this forum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16026/angular-diameter-perceived-size-of-objects).  But I can't find one that explains how to use this simple concept to determine on object's apparent size.

Comment: In many contexts, angular diameter is the same as apparent size. Is there a distinction between the two that you're trying to draw?

Comment: What does Angular Diameter mean?  In my case does it mean that the 10 meter wide widget positioned 1000 meters away will appear to be 0.572953020554149 meters wide?

Comment: Angular diameter is an angular measure, not a measure of length. You use the term in your question; do you understand it?

Comment: I understand that Angular Diameter is measured in degrees.  I'm trying to determine what the apparent size of a given object is at a specified distance.

Comment: Even simpler at what distance will a widget that is 10 meters wide appear to be 1 meter wide?

Answer (score 1):

From a physics perspective, angular diameter and "apparent size" are the same thing. They both essentially tell you how much of your vision the object is taking up.

> Even simpler at what distance will a widget that is 10 meters wide appear to be 1 meter wide?

There's no simple relationship between angular diameter and the apparent physical size of an object in meters. The apparent size of an object is psychological, not physical.

For instance, an adult human will appear to be in the ballpark of $1.6~\rm m$ tall from any distance, because you know from experience that's about how tall people are. Your brain uses many cues to estimate the physical size of objects in the distance.

Comment: While standing on Earth I can hold a ruler up to the sky and measure the Moon.  It will measure a couple of inches across.  That is not a subjective result.  There has to be an equation for this.

Comment: @DR01D Not really. You can measure a couple of inches at some distance, but that number will change as you move the ruler closer or farther away from your face. If you get touch the ruler to your eye then the "size" of the moon as measured this way gets to be infinite.

Comment: You are correct.  I'm looking for the equation that explains the way in which objects appear to change size as they move closer or further away from an observer.

Comment: @DR01D That's just the angular size. For instance the moon is about 31 arcminutes. It has no direct relation to any size in meters or any other linear distance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Ratio to your equations. If you know how big something is than add the ratio of that to the equation and do the math there... P.s. I'm horrible at math. It's just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an equation, here it is:

$$\tan{\theta} = \frac{D}{L}, $$

where $\theta$ is the angular diameter, $D$ is the true diameter, and $L$ is the distance. For things with small angular diameters, one can approximate:

$$ \tan{\theta} \approx \theta,$$

with the caveat that $\theta$ is measured in radians. (Note, your post had a unitless angle, which was in fact in degrees). For your hypothetical numbers:

$$ \theta \approx \frac{10\,m}{1000\,m} = 0.01\,rad = \frac{180}{100\pi}\, deg = 0.5729^{\circ},$$

where the numbers of significant figures reflects the accuracy of the small angle approximation.

Comment: How can I use that or a different equation to answer this simple question.  At what distance will a widget that is 10 meters wide appear to be 5 meters wide?

Comment: @DR01D What do you mean "appear 5 meters wide".  As long as the widget is 10m, it will appear 10m. Are you looking for a specific angular size? If that is so, then use the equation to solve for $L$.